# .net core app deployment on Azure doesn't bootstrap until a service is invoked

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, .net-core

Have an all RESTful service built using .NET core 1.1.  No front end.  This includes a couple of background tasks that run every other hour.  These tasks get bootstrapped (invoked) under the Configure method in the Startup class.

For some reason, nothing gets called when I publish my app onto Azure.  It seems that nothing gets runned in the Startup class at all.  I have to explicitly invoke a RESTful service to "start" it up and then everything seems to run fine.

I believe I'm doing something wrong here.  Is there a way to bootstrap my background tasks immediately when application gets published onto Azure?  I don't want to have to manually invoke a rest service just for the app to start up.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12154402/configuring-an-azure-website-with-application-warmup have you seen this?

Comment: You should use a WebJob for running taks instead of the App itself: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/03/07/how-to-deploy-a-net-core-console-application-to-azure-webjob/

Comment: @4c74356b41  That looks like the right idea but it didn't work for me since I don't have an initializationPage to point to.  I also just tried this:  <applicationInitialization doAppInitAfterRestart="true" skipManagedModules="true"/> but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

> tasks get bootstrapped (invoked) under the Configure method in the
>   Startup class.

You could manage to make it work, if the application runs inside a single instance. All you have to do is ping it from external service like [monitis](http://www.monitis.com/).

However, we need to deploy *two or more instances* in Azure to avoid a single point of failure. That means we should not run Background Tasks inside those instances; otherwise, we will end up with race condition.

For Background Tasks, you might want to consider using -

- [Azure Scheuler](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/)
- [Azure WebJob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-create-web-jobs)